# How am I able to search for usenames in a string?

Tags: php, function

I want the following:
I have a string, and I want to search usernames in that string from a database, for example:

```
"Dear user, xy xy xy, Kind Regards, me"
```

And than, I want to find all usernames in the string from a database and replace it with a link, for example (output from the function):

```
"Dear <a href="link.php?user=user">user</a>, xy xy xy, Kind Regards, <a href="link.php?user=me">me</a>"
```

To check all usernames I would use RedBeanPHP:

```
$alluser = R::getAll('SELECT * FROM user')
```

I've just created a code for it:

```
function mention($string) {
    $alluser = R::getAll('SELECT * FROM user');
    foreach ($alluser as $user) {
        //The Regular Expression filter
        $reg_exUrl = "/".$user['username']."/";
        if (preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $string, $usernames)) {
            foreach ($usernames as $username) {
                $search = $username;
                $replace = '<a href="user.php?tmpid='.$user['tmpid'].'">' . $user['username'] . '</a>';
                $string = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
                if (strlen($allmention) > 0) {
                    $spacecomma = ", ";
                } else $spacecomma = "";
                $allmention .= $spacecomma . $user['tmpid'];
            }
        }
    }

    return $string;

}
```

Throwing the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function mention(), 0 passed in xyz.php on line 65 and exactly 1 expected in xyz.php:34 Stack trace: #0 xyz.php(65): mention() #1 {main} thrown in xyz.php on line 34
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with the code you've posted. The error is in the code that calls the `mention` function. It should be called like

```
$result_string = mention($initial_string)
```

but judging be the error it is called like

```
$result_string = mention()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting array from database then can use [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to retrieve each username to generate your message.

Comment: and how can I do that, that like seach for the username, after that replace it with the link, and take note that 1 string maybe contain 1 OR more usernames also.